# Search in all JavaScript and CSS files in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Often, I would like to look for particular strings in the JavaScript or CSS of a webpage in Firefox. Today what I do is download the entire site for offline viewing and search that way, which is effective but cumbersome.

Is there a way to search across all JavaScript and CSS this way? (Assume that the browser has already downloaded the file as part of loading the page.)

Alternatively, if Firefox itself doesn't do this, is there something that can (e.g. an extension, a different browser)?

Answer (score 5):

- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the Developer Tools.
- Click the Debugger tab (if it isn't visible, click ❱❱ and select it from the list).
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Search#searching_in_all_files

[image]

> Click on any entry in the list to go directly to the line in the file where the string occurs.

Comment: However, in Firefox this works only for Debugger tab, i.e. for Javascript/Typescript sources, not for CSS. In Style Editor tab, I was not able to find any global search. In Developer Tools of Chrome and new Edge, fortunately there is just one tab called Sources, where you can search for JS or CSS (same shortcut, Shift + Control + F).

Comment: There is a feature request in Bugzilla asking for search across all sources participating in styling: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889571

Comment: This does not work. Shift + Command + F just toggles Firefox full screen on/off. Firefox version 102.0.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, it's possible to use the [Network tab search function](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/request_list/index.html#search-in-requests) in dev tools.
The search will honor filtered assets, if you have selected only CSS or JS for ex. it will make a full text search only on filtered XHR and JS requests.

It's basic but effective.

Remember that it's possible only to search in recorded requests, so it may be necessary to reload the page.

[image: network toolbar search screenshot 1 from the docs]

[image: network toolbar search screenshot 2 from the docs]